# Application C# for Skype

Tags: c#, skype

I just need a simple program that allows me to dial numbers and call via SkypeOut. I tried with Skype4, but I can't make a call. I just need to have 13 buttons (0 to 9 dial numbers) "+" "Call" "Finish". It will be for my car, and I need to develop it in C#. Can anyone help mi with that? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=142821

**Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Example Skype4COM
This Example Project with Source Code Supports ALL Event Handlers**